# Relating two tables in a database

Tags: database, database-design

I have a "Student" table which should have name column. But I made another table "StudentsName" for name since names have three parts: firstname, middlename and last name.
Now my question is how should I relate these two tables?

Comment: Why would you need 2 tables here? A student can only have one name.  I guess it's possible that two students could have the same first, middle, and last name, but not frequently enough to separate these.

Comment: Names have three parts?  Always?  I hope Eno (or Brian Peter George St John Le Baptiste De La Salle Eno as it says on his birth certificate) never registers for one of your classes.  Also, some cultures have many different ways of ordering name parts: the "firstname" may be the family name or the given name, depending in the student's background.

Comment: I suppose you could argue that your solution resolves my objections in the previous comment (by allowing any number of name parts, by allowing variable order of name parts).  The price of this flexibility is performance - open ended joins just to retrieve the Student with their name oarts.  Not to mention the additional complexity of data input.  On the plus side it could reduce the need for data cleansing when feeding a data warehouse, and provide a handle for reducing duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "student" table uses ids from "name" table then you want to have a FK from "students" to "name"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a primary key/foreign key constraint between the tables.  The only question is "which table is the controlling one?"  It could be the student table, in which case the name refers to the student ID in the student table.  Or, it could be the name table, where the student table records the current name for a student (and there might be other tables to record the history of this student's name changes - marriage, or just legal changes of name).